# Want a simple proof of the 'total differential of multi variable function'

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Average student here.

I was reading a math text by Mary boas and she gives me a formula to find the total differential of a multivariate function as $d u=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} d x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} d y+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} d z+\cdots$ where $u=f(x, y, z, \cdots)$.

I understood the above equation for a two variable case by using a geometrical argument known as 'tangent plane approximation' but for larger variables I couldn't prove it. Can anyone give a simple proof of the above equation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the intuitive idea:

To get from $(x,y,z)$ to a nearby point $(x+dx, y+ dy, z+ dz)$, first move a distance $dx$ in the $x$-direction, then move a distance $dy$ in the $y$-direction, then move a distance $dz$ in the $z$-direction. The value of $f$ changes by (approximately) $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx$ in the first step, then  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy$ in the second step, then  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} dz$ in the third step.

Comment: Thank you so much but I wanted a little bit more rigorous derivation than that.